# MySQL: How to update a table by counting matching records in another table related many-to-many

Tags: mysql, count, many-to-many

I have seen many posts on how to update a table with the count of matching records in another table when the other table is connected with a one-to-many relationship

However, I have just spent a day trying to update a table with the count of matching records in another table when the other table is connected with a many-to-many relationship.  I cannot find any posts on how to do that.  Any help is appreciated.

Any posts I have found about updating with many-to-many relationships show how to do it with a specific id, not as a loop through the entire dbase

The question is: When I have a pair of tables (A and B) related by a many-to-many relationship table (TableC), how do I loop through the entries in Table_B, matching only the ones matching Table_A.id for each loop, and Update the entry for num_done in each record of Table_A?

I have three tables (simplified version of actual columns):

- TableA: id, name, num_total (calculated), num_done (calculated), deleted
- Table B: id, status, deleted
- TableC: id, tableAid, tableBid, deleted

There could be many of Table B in Table a and many of Table A in Table B so TableC provides the many-to-many relationship table between them

I can show the information I want to use for the counts using

```
SELECT Table_A.id, Table_A.num_total, Table_B.status, COUNT(Table_B.id) AS num_status
FROM TableA AS Table_A
INNER JOIN TableC AS Table_A_Table_B ON Table_A.id = Table_A_Table_B.ida
INNER JOIN TableB AS Table_B ON Table_A_Table_B.idb = Table_B.id
WHERE 
Table_A.deleted = 0
AND Table_B.deleted = 0
AND Table_A_Table_B.deleted = 0
GROUP BY Table_A.id, Table_A.num_total, Table_B.status;
```

Which gives me the output of

```
+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------+------------+
| id                                   | num_total | status | num_status |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------+------------+
| 5e78895c-4c27-d734-a07c-643844205c5c |         9 | Done   |          9 |
| d6b0fc19-b112-b937-99ff-6495e53d5272 |         1 | Done   |          1 |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------+------------+
```

However
When I try to do this with an UPDATE command (I want to update the count for, say, num_done)
It gives me the total number of num_done across all matching records, NOT just across the ones for each Table_A.id

```
UPDATE TableA AS Table_A
INNER JOIN TableC AS Table_A_Table_B ON Table_A.id = Table_A_Table_B.ida
INNER JOIN TableB AS Table_B ON Table_A_Table_B.idb = Table_B.id 
SET Table_A.num_done = 
( 
SELECT COUNT(Table_B.id) 
FROM TableB AS Table_B 
INNER JOIN TableC AS Table_A_Table_B ON Table_B.id = Table_A_Table_B.idb
INNER JOIN TableA AS Table_A ON Table_A.id = TableA_Table_B.ida
WHERE 
Table_A.deleted = 0 
AND Table_B.deleted = 0 
AND Table_A_Table_B.deleted = 0  
AND Table_B.status = 'Done' 
)  
WHERE 
Table_A.deleted = 0 
AND Table_B.deleted = 0 
AND Table_A_Table_B.deleted = 0  
;
```

but when I try to add

```
GROUP BY Table_A.id
```

after

```
AND Table_B.status = 'Done'
```

I get an error saying the SubQuery is returning more than one entry (which it is)

So, when I have a pair of tables (A and B) related by a many-to-many relationship table (TableC), how do I loop through the entries in Table_B, matching only the ones matching Table_A.id for each loop, and Update the entry for num_done in each record of Table_A?